# How to give a field of an object the same type as a column of a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to a object with a field  that has the same type as column of a table.

```
create table TA (  
  TA_1          number
);

CREATE TYPE my_obj2 IS object
(
    TA_1            TA.TA_1%type
);
```

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Is it possible. If yes, what is wrong in this code?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=70faf9b6956122c3d7b6a3cf1d9cd8b4)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

The [CREATE TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TYPE-statement.html#GUID-389D603D-FBD0-452A-8414-240BBBC57034) document states:

> This data type must be stored in the database; that is, either a predefined data type or a user-defined standalone collection type.